# How to insert data to a CRM 2011 entity using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am quite sure that this is somehow a basic/stupid question but I just don't find the answer.

How do I insert a new record to an entity using Javascript (which is called on an `onChange` event)?

My aim is to insert 4 values read from an incident-form to a custom entity called `statuslog`.

It's easy enough to read the four fields.

```
// Statuscode: "1st Level Support"
var statuscodeTextValue = getPicklistValueText("statuscode");

// Incidentid: "AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEEE"
var incidentid = getGUIDOfCurrentRecord();

// Ownerid: "AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEEF"
var ownerid = getGUID("ownerid");

//timestamp is "Fri Oct 12 16:50:34 UTC +0200 2012"
var timestamp = new Date();
```

But what do I have to do next? A specific code example would be very much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the best example I have seen of this is on Gareth Tucker's excellent blog. In this post he creates a new Contact based on fields filled in on a phone call record. All code supplied, so you should be able to adapt to your custom entity and fields instead.

http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/08/23/quick-create-contact-from-the-phone-call-form/

Answer (score 0):

There are CRUD (Create, Read, Update & Delete) examples on the MSDN. I would suggest starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771584.aspx#BKMK_DataAccessUsingJavaScript), once you have decided on SOAP v REST just following the links. I would suggest starting with REST.

As a side, depending on your business problem, JavaScript may not be the best option here. It will only run when the form changes, e.g. a web service call or workflow that updates the record will not trigger the JavaScript. A [synchronous plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328490.aspx) maybe a better option here.

Comment: Thank you very much James. This will get me started.